# How to find stationary value of an area of a sector given that the radius can vary?

Tags: circles, differential

**Problem**: A sector of a circle, of a radius r cm, has a perimeter 200cm. Given that r can vary, find the stationary value of the area of the sector.

**Solution**: A=2500

**Attempt**:

```
Perimeter = rΘ + 2r

200 = rΘ + 2r

200 - 2r = rΘ

100 - r= 1/2 rΘ

100r - r^2 = 1/2 r^2Θ

Area = 100r - r^2
```

So I this is what I have so far and not sure how to continue.

Comment: Just differentiate your expression for the area and set it equal to zero to find $r$

Comment: @InzerLee: as I said in the post, you can insert $50$ in the formula for the area, obtaining: $$100\cdot50-50^2=2500$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a parabola with $a<0$. So, the stationary point is reached in the vertex of the parabola, which have coords:
$$V\left(-\frac{b}{2a},-\frac{\Delta}{4a}\right)$$
Substituing for $a,b$ and $c$, we have:
$$V\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{100^2}{4}\right)\implies V\left(\frac{1}{2},2500\right)$$
This shows that the area of the stationary point is $2500$.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Stack Exchange and I don't think I can +1 your post, really sorry about that